# Deploy flask by wfastcgi to IIS, logging not work in blueprint

Tags: iis, logging, flask, wfastcgi

I use python `logging`, it works well in simple code, when I deploy it on IIS using wfastcgi:

```
from flask import Flask
from LarkLog import LarkLog
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    LarkLog.Debug('hello!')
    return "Hello Stealth!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # manager.run() 
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5003, debug=True)
```

But when I deploy my real project which using blueprint, it works well except logging module not work. It does not logging anything, but an empty log file created.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I find it due to multi python.exe process(IIS?) concurrent running cause this, end all python.exe restart the IIS Web site it works well.

Comment: If you found the solution already, post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I have the same problem. are you setting debug = true in prod